# How to add C library to Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to add https://github.com/mlabbe/nativefiledialog this C library to my C++ project in visual studio 2022. I've built and generated the .lib file and added it to my project by going to Project->Properties->Linker. I added the path to this .lib file to Additional Library Directories. After doing this, I am still receiving "unresolved external symbol" linker errors. Specifically LNK2019 and LNK1120. I've also added the header file to the Additional Include Directories. What other steps am I missing?

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the code implementation:

StartupLayer.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "Walnut/Application.h"

#include "ExcelReader.h"
#include "nfd.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 255

class StartupLayer : public Walnut::Layer {

private:

    ExcelReader reader;
    char inputPath[BUFFER_SIZE] = "enter folder";

public:

    StartupLayer() : reader(ExcelReader()) {}

    ~StartupLayer() {}

    virtual void OnUIRender() override;

};
```

StartupLayer.cpp

```
#include "StartupLayer.h"

void StartupLayer::OnUIRender() {

    ImGui::Begin("Select Folder");
    ImGui::InputText("select folder", inputPath, BUFFER_SIZE);

    // when browse button is clicked
    if (ImGui::Button("Browse")) {

        nfdchar_t* outpath = NULL;
        nfdresult_t result = NFD_OpenDialog(NULL, NULL, &outpath);
    }

    ImGui::End();
}
```

It's a Dear ImGui project, and I wanted to use this open file dialog library in one of my layers. The above code is that layer class, and I'm getting the unresolved external symbol on the NFD_OpenDialog function call.

Comment: Can you provide your code/library implementation?

Comment: Just added the code implementation. Let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to add the path to the generated .lib file (nfd.lib) to Projects->Properties->Linker->Input Additional Dependencies. After doing this, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

## C Code

The C app contains just a little function:

```
// ./code/c/lib.c

#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void f()
{
    printf("\n This is a C code\n");
}
```

The keyword `__declspec(dllexport)` is only valid within the Microsoft compiler world and exports that function.

## Compile C

Open the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and navigate to the folder, where the C project is. Then simply type: `cl /LD lib.c`. This will create two files. A `lib.lib` and a `lib.dll`.

## C++ Code

Also nothing special. First you need the header file:

```
// ./code/cpp/Console/Console/Header.h

#pragma once

extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllimport) void f();
}
```

You find `declspec` again, but this time it is specified with `dllimport` which makes perfectly sense as you are importing the function

**Our app:**

```
// ./code/cpp/Console/Console/Console.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "../../../c/lib.lib")

int main()
{
  f();
}
```

Note the line `#pragma comment(lib, "../../../c/lib.lib")` which specifies the location of the `.lib` so the linker is able to reference the function `f()`.

## Execute

**If you now execute `Console.exe` you will get an error because the dll can not be find. To fix this, just copy the `lib.dll` to the folder where `Console.exe` is.**

[Source](https://dev.to/gabbersepp/call-a-c-library-from-c-3026).